# Do we need both a "userscript" and a "userscripts" tag?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

Do we need both "[userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscript/info)" and "[userscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info)" tags?
Someone's been retagging questions with these two tags, willy-nilly.

To me, either tag is like marking a question "code".  It adds no useful information -- especially for categories like "Greasemonkey" which imply a user-generated script, anyway.

I respectfully request that these two tags be merged or eliminated.

**Update:**
I manually merged/deleted the *userscript* tag from all questions.
<strike>[Please vote to approve *userscript* as a synonym for *userscripts* at this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/synonyms)</strike>   Done, thanks!

Now, holding out hope for a purge or a justification for the "userscripts" tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to merge the tags then

- pick which tag you want to keep e.g `userscripts`
- retag all questions that use `userscript` to `userscripts`
- suggest a synonym so that any future questions tagged with `userscript` will automagically get tagged with `userscripts`
- sit back and wait for your synonym suggestion to be approved.

If you want to delete both tags then I suggest retagging all the questions and then asking a moderator to delete the tags. Although that won't stop anyone from recreating them of course.

Comment: Moderators do not need to delete tags. They are automatically deleted if there is no questions attached. This is cached though so normally wait a few hours for it to be removed.

Comment: @Diago - thanks for the clarification.  I wasn't 100% sure if a Mod needed to delete the tag or not.

Comment: Thanks, Barry.  I may end up merging the tags the hard way, but moderators have "disappeared" tags that I thought were useful (EG "Beginner") in a more permanent way.  I'm hoping that's what will happen here.  Or, perhaps, we'll learn that these 2 tags are somehow useful in some small way.

Comment: @Brock Not moderators. Developers. Small distinction :)

Comment: @Diago:  Developers can terminate a tag with prejudice, so that, for example, a "sorry, the 'beginner' tag is not allowed." message is triggered?

Comment: @Brock They have access to the black list. So Yes.